# Is it possible to fill List<Interface> with items from a normal string list in c#

Tags: c#

First time dealing with a problem like this and i was wondering if it was even possible before spending a lot of time trying. If it is, would someone please explain/show me how.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you want to know is if a `List<IComparable>` can be filled out? If yes, of course, `l.Add(obj)` where `obj` implements `IComparable`.

Comment: Please see [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the interface of your list is one that strings implement, it's possible:

```
// These interfaces are all implemented by the 'String' class
List<IComparable> foo1 = new List<IComparable>();
List<ICloneable> foo2 = new List<ICloneable>();
List<IConvertible> foo3 = new List<IConvertible>();
List<IComparable<String>> foo4 = new List<IComparable<string>>();
List<IEnumerable<char>> foo5 = new List<IEnumerable<char>>();
List<IEquatable<String>> foo6 = new List<IEquatable<string>>();

// A list of strings to add to any of the lists above
List<string> strings = new List<string> { "Hello", "world!" };

// Add a list of strings, and add a single string
foo1.AddRange(strings);
foo1.Add("And goodbye, cruel world");

// Output the results
foreach(IComparable item in foo1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Genuinely exactly what i wanted, thank u so much :)